# How to put an ARPlaneAnchor at the same location as an ARImageAnchor

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm trying to place an ARImageAnchor at the same location as an ARPlaneAnchor but it is not working. Here is the start of my `renderer` function where I believe the problem lies:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let imageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
        ...
}
```

When I take comment out everything pertaining to planeAnchor it works fine, but once I try to put them at the same location it still compiles but it doesnt detect the reference images. Anyone see a problem like this before? Thanks!

UPDATE: With sceneView as my ARSCNView, I use this code:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    print("got here")
    guard let touchLocation = touches.first?.location(in: sceneView),
        let hitTest = sceneView?.hitTest(touchLocation, options: nil),
        //let detectedPlane = planes[planeAnchor],
        let nodeTapped = hitTest.first?.node,
        let nodeName = nodeTapped.name else { return }
    print("got here 2")

    print(nodeName)

}
```

but "got here 2" is never printed and nothing happens when I tap on the plane. What should I try?

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to add a plane anchor at the same location? This may enable me to assist :)

Comment: Absolutely. I'm trying to detect planes from a reference image and get some values such as the image height, width, and name, and then use those values to create a plane node as you showed me in my last question with the same height, width, and name, but creating PlaneNode requires an ARPlaneAnchor, not an ARImageAnchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had a further look I don't this is possible.

If you set your `ARWorldTrackingConfiguration` to detect planes e.g:

```
  configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal
```

Then in the delegate method add this debug log:

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    print(anchor.classForCoder)

}
```

You will see that when you have detected your target image it will log `ARImageAnchor` whereas if it detects a horizontal plane it will log: `ARPlaneAnchor`.

This is why your guard statement isn't exectuting:

```
 guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else { return }
```

Simply because there cannot be two anchors at the same time...

There is either an `ARPlaneAnchor` or an `ARImageAnchor`.

An **update** based on your last response, which will allow you to get these properties:

```
   func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {

    //1. If Out Target Image Has Been Detected Than Get The Corresponding Anchor
    guard let currentImageAnchor = anchor as? ARImageAnchor else { return }

    //2. Get The Targets Name
    let name = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.name!

    //3. Get The Targets Width & Height
    let width = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.width
    let height = currentImageAnchor.referenceImage.physicalSize.height

    //4. Log The Reference Images Information
    print("""
    Image Name = \(name)
    Image Width = \(width)
    Image Height = \(height)
    """) 
}
```

I still don't understand however why you need a PlaneAnchor as well, you can just use this to display models etc :)

If you want to add something at that Anchor then try this:

```
  /// Generates An SCNPlane On The Detected Image At The Size Of The Target
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - node: SCNNode
///   - width: CGFloat
///   - height: CGFloat
func generateModel(_ node: SCNNode, width: CGFloat, height: CGFloat){

    let nodeToAdd = SCNNode()
    let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: width, height: height)
    planeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.red
    nodeToAdd.geometry = planeGeometry
    nodeToAdd.transform = SCNMatrix4MakeRotation(-Float.pi / 2, 1, 0, 0)
    node.addChildNode(nodeToAdd)
}
```

And call it in the delegate method:

```
 generateModel(node, width: width, height: height)
```

I think this is what you are trying to achieve.

**Update:** To get a hitTest on the added node just use touchesBegan e.g.

```
   override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    guard let touch = touches.first?.location(in: self.augmentedRealityView),
    let hitTest = self.augmentedRealityView?.hitTest(touch, options: nil),
    let nodeTapped = hitTest.first?.node,
    let nodeName = nodeTapped.name else { return }

    print(nodeName)

}
```

**Update:**
If the object placed on the `ImageAnchor` seems shaky it could be that you have set the `referenceImage` size incorrectly in your ARAssets Bundle:

[image]

Comment: I understand the code you shared, but now after I have that name, width, and height info, how do I create a PlaneNode with those values at the location of the detected image?

Comment: Still a little bit confused. I'm setting up PlaneNode like this: `let planeNode = PlaneNode(anchor: planeAnchor, node: node, image: true, identifier: self.planes.keys.count, opacity: 0.85, width: self.rWidth, height: self.rHeight, name: self.rName)` and already have code similar to what you posted in my PlaneNode class. Doesnt creating a plane at a certain location require an anchor so it knows where the plane is supposed to be set?

Where rWidth, rHeight, and rName are global variables with the values stored in them

Comment: When you create an SCNNode, and anchor is added automatically to the Scene :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for bearing with me. So I make those changes but now I'm back to where I started and now I cannot run the hittest on it because the hittest function you gave me requires an ARPlaneAnchor to store it in the dictionary `planes`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So do you want to detect a hit on the node which was added in the GenerateModelFunction?

Comment: Also, the plane that is placed is very shaky. How do other people make the plane/3D object so stationary? This one jumps around a lot.

Comment: Yes, I want to detect a hit on the node after it's been added

Comment: Updated code. This should be enough to get you on your way :)

Comment: So I just updated my question. It's still not functioning right.

Comment: Hey Josh, so I'm still struggling a lot with this. How do I get the parent anchor of the node so that when I place the 3D object, it's not so shaky? I want to add a 3D object to the imageanchor that was added with the image detection in the renderer function. Is there a way to get the parent anchor of a 3d plane with the hittest? So when I tap on a PlaneNode, it returns the name of the plane, along with the parent anchor so I can then add a 3D object from a dae file onto that anchor. Any help you could give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: One reason the object could be shaky is that you haven't set the Reference Image Sizes correctly. they should be accurate as possible to prevent shaking and inaccurate tracking... See update...

Comment: They are as accurate as they can be. Measured down to within the inch.

Comment: You can get the anchor of a node like so:  augmentedRealityView?.anchor(for: SCNODE)

Comment: So that helped a lot. Like, a lot. So thank you for that! It's still slightly moving, but this time it's a little different movement type. It seems as though distance does not matter. The PlaneNode stays stationary, but when I move closer to the image ( a poster on my wall, roughly 5 ft away) the planenode moves forward with me and I never get close to the planenode on my screen.